# Creating Bundle for Java 7 jar file on MacOS manually

Tags: java, macos

I'm reading through documentation and have created an app bundle (using Finder, Terminal and TextEdit) as follows:

```
GUITest.app/
    Contents/
        Info.plist
        PkgInfo
        MacOS/
            JavaAppLauncher
        Resources/
            GenericJavaApp.icns
            Java/
                gui.jar
```

However when I try double clicking on the finder, the icon has a "no entry" sign on it, and when I double-click, I get: `The application "GUITest" can't be opened. -10810`

If I try kicking off the JavaAppLauncher manually:
`./GUITest.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaAppLauncher` I get a dialog with "`JRELoadError`"

The Info.plist seems pretty straightforward.
PkgInfo is just `AAPL????` and the JavaAppLauncher is from the http://java.net/projects/appbundler/downloads/download/appbundler-1.0.jar

Could these problems be down to a bad `Info.plist` or something else?

Here is the Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>JavaAppLauncher</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>GenericApp.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>gui.GUITest</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>GUITest</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>GUITest</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>©xirt, 2014</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.developer-tools</string>
    <key>JVMRuntime</key>
    <string>jdk1.7.0_17.jdk</string>
    <key>JVMMainClassName</key>
    <string>main.GUITest</string>
    <key>JVMOptions</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>JVMArguments</key>
    <array>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Note: the no entry sign was removed by removing the com.apple.quarantine extended attribute:
`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine JavaAppLauncher`
But the problem still occurs:

```
$ open ./GUITest.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/.../GUITest.app.
```

The error above can be re-created if the process simply fails.  For example, replacing JavaAppLauncher with the following shell script reproduces the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
return -1
```

So, I suppose I have to look at why `JavaAppLauncher` fails...

Comment: Post the `info.plist`, for it might just be a matter of not having the path to the runtime set correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay - it took some figuring but there were a number of issues.  Ultimately, I recompiled my own JavaAppLauncher from the app bundler source and stepped through it in Xcode (so much for helpful documentation!).
https://java.net/projects/appbundler

1. The JDK reference seemed to be wrong, so removing the JVM Runtime key `<key>JVMRuntime</key>
   <string>jdk1.7.0_17.jdk</string>` helped here.
2. The Java directory needed to be at the Contents level, not Resources.

   ```
   GUITest.app/
       Contents/
           Info.plist
           PkgInfo
           MacOS/
               JavaAppLauncher
           Resources/
               GenericJavaApp.icns
           Java/
              gui.jar
   ```
3. After fixing these issues, despite two separate applications showing identical `diff`s, one worked while the other showed error `-1080`(!). Removing the extended attributes solved the problem: `xattr -lr GUITest.app`.

see also the java.net page on Packaging:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html